# What is the formula for calculating Ethereum block size in megabytes?

Tags: blockchain

I know that the Ethereum block size is bounded by gas limit, But I need to know the size in megabytes. There is a chart in [YChart](https://ycharts.com/indicators/ethereum_average_block_size) That represents block size in bytes, But they say: "there's not a formula that would calculate bytes based on block gas limit. The Ethereum data on YCharts exists as static economic indicator data sets taken directly from the Ethereum Statistics report published by Etherscan"

How can I calculate it by the gas limit or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs on ethereum.org:

> A final important note is that blocks themselves are bounded in size. Each block has a target size of 15 million gas but the size of blocks will increase or decrease in accordance with network demands, up until the block limit of 30 million gas (2x target block size).

From the above, the size of the block changes dynamically based on network demands, so I don't think there is a formula that could take into accounts unforeseen demands to calculate the block size in MB based on the block gas limit. In other words, block gas limit is not the sole factor that can be used to determine the block size.

See: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/blocks/